# powerhsell remote wmi query failing

Tags: powershell, wmi

The following query asks for the credential password but then fails (I've also tried putting -credential between -computer and -filter:

```
$running = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -computer servname -filter "Name =‘process.exe’” -credential domain\administrator
foreach ($objItem in $running){
write-host $objitem.Path
}
```

The error is:

```
PS C:\Users\ME> $running = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -compute
r servername -filter "Name = 'process.exe'" -credential domain\administrator
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query
At line:1 char:25
+ $running = Get-WMIObject <<<<  Win32_Process -computer 172.20.10.114 -filter
"Name = 'process.exe'" -credential domain\administrator
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], Managemen
   tException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
   ommands.GetWmiObjectCommand

PS C:\Users\ME> foreach ($objItem in $running){
>> write-host $objitem.Path
>> }
>>
```

Thanks, Charlotte.

Comment: I'm going to assume Christian has the right answer, and just add a debugging comment. You focused on the fact that PowerShell asked for your password then failed, and missed the actual problem. Note the error carefully, "Invalid Query." If you're trying to attack a problem like this, your next step should be to change the query in some way. Perhaps try a filter from the help files and see if that works. Then try to change it to exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy & paste this:

```
$running = Get-WMIObject Win32_Process -computer servname -filter "Name ='process.exe'” -credential domain\administrator
```

check the char (')!